GitHub Actions: Use same version of psql and PostgreSQL service
This is my job:
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:17
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          - 5432:5432

    steps:
      - name: Check version of pg_restore
        run: pg_restore -V

      - name: Check version of psql
        run: psql -V

      - name: Check version of postgres
        run: psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres -c 'select version()'
        env:
          PGPASSWORD: postgres

It outputs this:

pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 14.13 (Ubuntu 14.13-1.pgdg22.04+1)


psql (PostgreSQL) 14.13 (Ubuntu 14.13-1.pgdg22.04+1)


PostgreSQL 17.0 (Debian 17.0-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit

I guess that is because ubuntu-latest comes with PostgreSQL 14.13.
What's the best practice to have both versions synchronized? I need this because I want to restore a dump created with pg_dump 17.0.

did you check my answer, isn't it helpful?

@AlwaysSunny Yeah, that's basically what I already did but I wasn't sure if this is the best solution because it's kind of wasteful.

There are a few options to have PostgreSQL versions synchronized in your GitHub Actions workflow, Here is the one with expected output.
name: PostgreSQL Version Sync(Standalone)

on: [workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:17
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          - 5432:5432

    steps:
      # Step to install PostgreSQL 17 client tools
      - name: Add PostgreSQL 17 repository
        run: |
          sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
          wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-client-17

      # Ensure PostgreSQL 17 binaries are used by exporting the correct PATH
      - name: Check version of pg_restore
        run: |
          export PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/17/bin:$PATH"
          pg_restore -V

      - name: Check version of psql
        run: |
          export PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/17/bin:$PATH"
          psql -V

      - name: Check version of postgres
        run: |
          export PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/17/bin:$PATH"
          psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres -c 'select version()'
        env:
          PGPASSWORD: postgres

Output:

